# Telegram TCP obfuscated transport not receiving data

Tags: java, kotlin, aes, mtproto

I'm trying to implement the MTProto transport obfuscation capability described [here](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/mtproto-transports#transport-obfuscation).
I've followed instructions letter per letter, to no avail: data is sent, e.g. for `ReqPqMulti`, but upon reading the response, e.g. `ResPQ`, the input stream blocks forever, which means no data is received.

The initialization payload and the AES Cipher are created as follow. See also comments.

```
fun buildInitPayload(header: Byte?): Pair<AES, ByteArray> {
   // Add the padded transport header to the reserved words
   val reservedWords = if (header != null) {
      reservedWords + byteArrayOf(header, header, header, header)
   } else {
      reservedWords
   }
   
   val primaryPayload = ByteArray(64)
   val secureRandom = SecureRandom()

   // Generate 64-byte random initialization payload
   do {
      secureRandom.nextBytes(primaryPayload)
   } while (!isInitPayloadValid(reservedWords, primaryPayload))

   if (header != null) {
      primaryPayload[56] = header
      primaryPayload[57] = header
      primaryPayload[58] = header
      primaryPayload[59] = header
   }

   // Extract two keys from both initialization payloads, using bytes at offsets 8-40:
   // the key extracted from the primary payload is used as encryption key
   val encryptionKey = primaryPayload.copyOfRange(8, 40)

   // Generate a secondary initialization payload by reversing the primary payload
   val secondaryPayload = ByteArray(48)
   for (i in 0..47) secondaryPayload[i] = primaryPayload[55 - i]

   // The key extracted from the secondary payload is used as decryption key
   val decryptionKey = secondaryPayload.copyOf(32)

   // Extract two IVs from both initialization payloads, using bytes at offsets 40-56:
   // the IV extracted from the primary payload is used as encryption IV,
   // the IV extracted from the secondary payload is used as decryption IV.
   val encryptionIV = primaryPayload.copyOfRange(40, 56)
   val decryptionIV = secondaryPayload.copyOfRange(32, 48)

   val aes = AES(encryptionKey, encryptionIV, decryptionKey, decryptionIV)
   val encryptedPayload = aes.encryptCTR(primaryPayload)

   return aes to primaryPayload.copyOf(56) + encryptedPayload.copyFrom(56)
}
```

The AES-CTR Cipher is initialized using

```
private val encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding")

init {
   encryptionCipher.init(
      Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,
      SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey, "AES"),
      IvParameterSpec(encryptionIV)
   )
}
```

Using the Abridged transport (non-obfuscated) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If using the abridged transport works and the obfuscated transport simply never respond it's likely you've missed the padding needed for the padded intermediate transport with obfuscation as described here: https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/mtproto-transports#padded-intermediate